# Problem while running example code from CredentialsContainer.create docs

Tags: javascript, webauthn

total FE noob here.
I'm trying to follow these instructions on the `create` method relative to the Web Authentication API described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer/create).

I'm getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: CredentialContainer request is not allowed.
```

when running the example code from the above site:

```
let credential = navigator.credentials.create({
    publicKey: {
      challenge: window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(8)),
      rp: { id: "acme.com", name: "ACME Corporation" },
      user: {
        id: new Uint8Array([79, 252, 83, 72, 214, 7, 89, 26]),
        name: "jamiedoe",
        displayName: "Jamie Doe"
      },
      pubKeyCredParams: [ {type: "public-key", alg: -7} ]
    }
  });
```

I have two questions:

1. what am I doing wrong?
2. is there a way to make the error message more explicit? Yeah, probably doesn't like the request... but what bit exactly? How do you approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this in Firefox? Does the same error happen in Chrome?

It appears that the error would come [from here](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/credentialmanagement/CredentialsContainer.cpp#230):

`if (!IsSameOriginWithAncestors(mParent) || !IsInActiveTab(mParent))`

Are you trying to do the call in a cross-origin iframe, or from an inactive tab?

Comment: Yeah I'm on FF... how did you pin the specific line where the exception is thrown? I simply have a ```login.html``` and a ```login.js``` containing the above code. I don't know which of the two options you're describing I'm in.

Comment: on GC I get: ```Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: This is an invalid domain.```

Comment: Are you opening the files from the local filesystem? I think you'll need to serve them over HTTPS. WebAuthn credentials are scoped to an "RP ID" (basically a website) and the local filesystem isn't a website so there's no scope that the browser can use.